# Random number generator for the vector in R

Tags: r, random

I have a question when I try to replicate the results, I come up with a problem.

```
l <- {}
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(1)
  l[i] <- rnorm(n = 1, i, i)  
}
```

this will produce

```
0.3735462 0.7470924 1.1206386
```

However, if I write

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(n = 3, 1:3, 1:3)
0.3735462 2.3672866 0.4931142
```

Or

```
set.seed(1)
rmvnorm(n = 1, 1:3, sqrt(diag(1:3)))
0.3735462 2.21839 1.900251
```

I don't get the same result. What can a be a problem?
My goal is to vectorize the for loop, that's why I come up with a problem.

**UPDATE**

The answer below explains, how it works for *rnorm* and should work for all random number generators in R, however when I try this approach with *rgig* (Generalized Inverse Gaussian Distribution) I have again a problem.

```
l <- {}
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(1)
  l[i] <- rgig(n = i, i, i, i)[i]
}
1.629091 1.500733 1.564364
```

and if I use

```
set.seed(1)
rgig(n = 3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
1.629091 1.440166 3.264135
```

When I use

```
sapply(1:3,function(x){set.seed(1);rgig(x,x,x,x)})
```

It doesn't show similar pattern as for *rnorm*.
My assumption that it *rgig* doesn't support vectorization, since if we write:

```
set.seed(1)
rgig(n = 3, 1, 1, 1)
1.629091 1.440166 3.264135
```

What is the same as for vectorized. Am I right?

Comment: What are your expected results? I'm not sure I quite understand what it is about the 2nd 2 examples you don't want.

Comment: The best way to is to change the line as `rnorm(1, 1)` and run it again. The output will explain the logic.

Comment: @griffmer, My expected results is that vectorized random number generator and for loop generator will produce the same result if I use set.seed. I have two R codes and I want to compare them, but one uses for loops and another (mine) vectorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first method

```
l <- {}
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(1)
  l[i] <- rnorm(n = 1, i, i)  
}
0.3735462 0.7470924 1.1206386
```

for the second method

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(n = 3, 1:3, 1:3)
0.3735462 2.3672866 0.4931142
```

Your question is why are the two methods not producing the same results?.

Well to answer this i would first say before hand that the two methods DO PRODUCE CONSISTENT RESULTS. now lets see why the values from the pseudorandom generation are different.
the simplet way is run a for-loop to see what happens:

```
sapply(1:3,function(x){set.seed(1);rnorm(x,x,x)})
[[1]]
[1] 0.3735462 #One number produced from mu=1 sd=1    
[[2]]
[1] 0.7470924 2.3672866 # Two numbers produced from mu=2 sd=2    
[[3]]
[1] 1.1206386 3.5509300 0.4931142  # Three numbers produced from mu=3 sd=3
```

Now if you look at this list, you will notice that the for loop is just taking the first numbers while the second method just takes the last numbers produced. That is why the numbers are different But in the end, the result is consistent since as you can see, both numbers are produced by the same mean and sd

Thus

```
 set.seed(1)
 rnorm(3,1:3,1:3)

is equivalent to

l <- {}
for(i in 1:3){
  set.seed(1)
  l[i] <- rnorm(n = i, i, i)[i]  
}
l
[1] 0.3735462 2.3672866 0.4931142
rnorm(3,1:3,1:3)
[1] 0.3735462 2.3672866 0.4931142
```

Comment: Thank you! It answers my question. One additional comment, maybe you know how to make reproducible results if I don't want to change for loops (you slightly changed it). If I stay with an initial for loop, how I can get the same numbers using a vectorized expression. (just for curiosity)

Comment: Since the for loop gives the very first number generated while the vectorized gives the last number generated, there is no way to get the values of the for-loop match the vectorized values without twisting the for loop the way i did above. Since also you are dealing with random number generation, it doesnot matter what method you use. Both will give you the correct conclusion. Its only that the vectorized method will be faster and efficient

Answer (score 2):

With your loop, you do this:

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(n = 1, 1, 1)
set.seed(1)
rnorm(n = 1, 2, 2)
set.seed(1)
rnorm(n = 1, 3, 3)
```

With your 2nd line of code you do this:

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(3, 1:3, 1:3)
```

Hence the different results.
In other words: with the loop you do set.seed(1) and randomly pick 1 number 3 times, at first you draw a number from a distribution with a mean and sd of 1, then from a mean and sd of 2 for the 2nd and at last from a mean and sd of 3 for the 3rd.

With the other you sample 3 numbers directly from a vector of means and sd's consisting of 1, 2 and 3. Then the seed was used for one line of code in which all three 3 numbers were generated.

If you would have liked to get the same results with your for loop, you would have needed this code:

```
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm(n = 1, 1, 1) 
[1] 0.3735462
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm(n = 1, 2, 2)
[1] 0.7470924
> set.seed(1)
> rnorm(n = 1, 3, 3)
[1] 1.120639
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my goal is to find the way that vectorized version produces the same results as for loop.